# Poor quality compiler optimization in c#

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization, cil

I don't know why but I watched the IL generated from the standard c# compiler (VS2015) and it's dramatically non optimized in release mode.

The code that I tested is very simple:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 25 + 7/3;
        count += 100;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", count);
    }
```

The IL output in debug mode is:

```
// [12 9 - 12 10]
IL_0000: nop          

// [34 13 - 34 34]
IL_0001: ldc.i4.s     27 // 0x1b
IL_0003: stloc.0      // count

// [35 13 - 35 26]
IL_0004: ldloc.0      // count
IL_0005: ldc.i4.s     100 // 0x64
IL_0007: add          
IL_0008: stloc.0      // count

// [36 13 - 36 45]
IL_0009: ldstr        "{0}"
IL_000e: ldloc.0      // count
IL_000f: box          [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0014: call         void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string, object)
IL_0019: nop          

// [37 9 - 37 10]
IL_001a: ret
```

and the code in Release mode is:

```
 IL_0000: ldc.i4.s     27 // 0x1b
IL_0002: stloc.0      // V_0
IL_0003: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_0004: ldc.i4.s     100 // 0x64
IL_0006: add          
IL_0007: stloc.0      // V_0
IL_0008: ldstr        "{0}"
IL_000d: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_000e: box          [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0013: call         void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string, object)
IL_0018: ret
```

Now, Why the compiler are not perform the sum (27 + 100) and direct call WriteLine with 127 ?

I tried the same sample in c++ and it works as expected.

There's some special flag to perform this kind optimization?

UPDATE:
I try the same code on MONO 4.6.20 and the result in release mode is the following

```
 // method line 2
.method private static hidebysig
       default void Main (string[] args)  cil managed
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2058
    .entrypoint
    // Code size 18 (0x12)
    .maxstack 8
    IL_0000:  ldstr "{0}"
    IL_0005:  ldc.i4.s 0x7f
    IL_0007:  box [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_000c:  call void class [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string, ob                                                                                                                               ject)
    IL_0011:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Update 2024

I reatry with new compiler .net core 8 and finaly the code are optimize directly in IL

```
.custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute::.ctor(uint8) = (
    01 00 01 00 00
)
// Method begins at RVA 0x2050
// Header size: 12
// Code size: 25 (0x19)
.maxstack 2
.entrypoint
.locals init (
    [0] int32 count
)

IL_0000: ldc.i4.s 27
IL_0002: stloc.0
IL_0003: ldloc.0
IL_0004: ldc.i4.s 100
IL_0006: add
IL_0007: stloc.0
IL_0008: ldstr "{0}"
IL_000d: ldloc.0
IL_000e: box [System.Runtime]System.Int32
IL_0013: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string, object)
IL_0018: ret
```

Comment: Are you sure you allowed optimization in `release` mode?

Comment: Yes, i have also disabled the extra debug or trace out

Comment: Have you looked at the JIT compiled code? In .NET, most genuine optimization is performed by the JIT, not the C# compiler.

Comment: No, I don't know the way to get the final x86 code.

Comment: It's often fairly tricky (it's been a while since I've used cordbg or windbg) - but what you *could* do is benchmark the code with and without manual optimization. If it performs the same way, presumably you don't care - or rather, I'd personally prefer the current IL generated that makes it simpler to step through even release code in a debugger.

Comment: @JonSkeet I usually get to it by attaching the Visual Studio debugger to the running process and using the context menu to "Go To Disassembly".  This will show the x86 inline with the C# usually (although it'll duplicate some lines that don't match up quite right).  That's the easiest way I know of.

Comment: One note to the instructions from @Kyle you must make sure that the code you want to see the disassembly has already executed at least once so the code will have already been JITed before you attach the debugger. Having the code be JITed while the debugger has been attached will cause different assembly code to be generated.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, usually you can ensure that by putting a breakpoint on the first executable statement and then letting it get hit. But, yes, if you don't let executing enter the method first chances are the JIT hasn't even run on the method yet and there won't be anything to look at.

Comment: The compiler being "bad" at outputting "optimized" IL is generally a feature, not a bug. Having an obvious relation between the source code and the target IL code makes it easier to judge correctness of the compiler and makes it easier for the jitter to recognize patterns and optimize them. Remember, the compiler cannot optimize for the target platform (yet) since it's only outputting IL, so it's beneficial to delegate most of this stuff to the jitter, where all information is available.

Comment: In the overwhelming majority of cases the compiler does know what the platform is though (you could specify it statically in most programs without issue) . I would have thought tightly coupling the optimisation of the msil and the final asm would be beneficial. Firstly it reduces JIT overhead, secondly the compiler has full scope of the program, I may be wrong but I though the JIT could only do micro optimisations of individual methods not entire programs.

Answer (score 5):

You can't rely on the IL output of the compiler to accurately assess how optimized the code is, because the JIT is going to get its hand on the IL at runtime to generate the actual code to run.  In this case the actual x64 emitted by the JIT (in Release mode for Any CPU without Prefer 32-bit) looks like this:

```
sub         rsp,28h  
mov         rcx,7FFF85323E98h  
call        00007FFF91C72530  ; I'm not sure what this call does, I assume it's allocating memory for the boxed int
mov         rcx,20CA5CB3648h  
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx]  ; After this rcx is actually pointing to the string "{0}"
mov         dword ptr [rax+8],7Fh ; Box the value 127 into the object that rax points at
mov         rdx,rax  
call        00007FFF85160070  ; Call Console.WriteLine with its arguments in rcx and rdx
nop  
add         rsp,28h  
ret
```

So the extra edition gets elided.

If I turn on "Prefer 32-bit", the emitted x86 looks like this:

```
mov         ecx,72041638h  
call        011630F4  ; presumably allocating memory for the boxed int
mov         edx,eax  
mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[40E232Ch] ; loads a pointer to "{0}" into eax
mov         dword ptr [edx+4],7Fh  ; boxes 127 into object pointed at by edx
mov         ecx,eax  
call        71F373F4  ; calls Console.WriteLine with arguments in ecx and edx
ret
```

In both cases the JIT optimized out the local variable as well as the extra addition operations.  Since the JIT performs so many optimizations, you'll find that the C# compiler itself doesn't go to great lengths to optimize anything.

**tl;dr** The emitted IL from the C# compiler is not what the machine runs and so is not generally representative of the sorts of optimizations will be applied.

Comment: Can the JIT perform program assembly wide optimisations, or is it's scope limited to the  class / method?